# Does save(:validate=>false) stop a counter_cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

My question is pretty much the subject line:

If I want to save a record but forego all validations, will it still update the relevant `counter_cache`s when it receives the call `@record.save(:validate => false)`?

How does Rails treat `counter_cache` with respect to validations, and is there a command that controls each individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass :validate=>false, it skips the valid? function call. Everything else works as expected.

Comment: So for clarity, `counter_cache` does not fall under the `valid?` function call?

Comment: nope... there is another method called increment_counter that increments the counter_cache column. This is not related to validations